# How to export / save a fitted model after cross_validate and use it later on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using cross_validate sklearn-function to fit a RandomForest classifier.
I'd like to know if there's a way to export the fitted model(s) to save them and import to predict new data.

I tried to use the `return_estimator=True` option

> [return_estimator : boolean, default False Whether to return the
>   estimators fitted on each split.]

and then `joblib` to save the estimators. But when I load the saved model and try to use it to `predict`, I got an error, (see below).

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
cv_results = cross_validate(rfc, X_train_std ,Y_train, scoring=scoring, cv=5, return_estimator=True)
rfc_fit = cv_results['estimator']

#save estimated model
savedir = ('C://Users//.......//src//US//') 

from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = os.path.join(savedir, 'final_model.joblib')
joblib.dump(rfc_fit,filename)

rfc_model2 = joblib.load(filename)
bla = rfc_model2.predict(X_test_std)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I guess I am confused on what really the `return_estimator` give back..
it looks like they're not the fitted models. So, is there a way to extrace the model fitted during the cross-validation in order to re-use them?

thanks

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: Thank you! it seems to be fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`return_estimator` returns the 'tuple' of ALL the fitted models.**

**To solve this, you need to select the desired model, save it, load it and then predict.**

**Example:**

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()

cv_results = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3, return_estimator=True)
rfc_fit = cv_results['estimator']
print(rfc_fit)
```

The above prints 3 models:

> (Lasso(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,
>   normalize=False, positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None, 
>   selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False), Lasso(alpha=1.0,
>   copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,    normalize=False,
>   positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None,
>   selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False), Lasso(alpha=1.0,
>   copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,    normalize=False,
>   positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None,
>   selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False))

**To see how many models this contains do this:**

```
print(len(rfc_fit))
# 3
```

**Let's say you want to select the first model:**

```
# select the first model
rfc_fit = rfc_fit[0]

# save it
from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = os.path.join(savedir, 'final_model.joblib')
joblib.dump(rfc_fit,filename)

# load it
rfc_model2 = joblib.load(filename)
```

**`Predict` works fine now:**

```
predicted = rfc_model2.predict(X)
```